# Hibernate isn't inserting foreign key ManyToOne entitiy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I would like to know why Hibernate isnt inserting foreign key into the database.

I have a OneToMany and ManyToOne relation between 2 classes.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Bestelling {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bestelling_id")
    private long bestellingID;

    private Date bestelDatum;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account accountID_fk;

    @JoinColumn(name = "adres_id")
    @OneToOne
    private Adres afleverAdres;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bestelling")
    private List<Bestellingsregel> bestellingsregels = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

AND

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Bestellingsregel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bestellingsregel_id")
    private long bestellingsregelID;

    private int aantal;
    private double prijs;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bestelling_id")
    private Bestelling bestelling;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product productID;
}
```

I'm using Postman to insert data into my MySql database:

```
{

"bestelDatum" : "2019-02-28",
"accountID_fk" : {
                    "accountID" : 1 
                },
"afleverAdres" : {
                    "adres_id" : 1
                },
"bestellingsregels" : [
                    { "aantal" : 5,
                      "prijs" : 100.50,
                      "productID" : { "productID" : 1 }
                    }
                    ]
}
```

It's making an insert into the database. The only problem is that it isn't setting the bestelling_id in table Bestellingsregel. Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm using Spring and the crud functions are inside this interface:

```
public interface BestellingRepository extends JpaRepository<Bestelling, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Please show the java-method used to insert the data.

Comment: Dear Peter. The java-methods are inside the JpaRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definied relationship between Bestelling and Bestellingsregel as bidirectional with owning side (holding foreign key) at Bestellingsregel, which is correct, but has pros and cons.

You have following options:

1. Use your relationship as definied and set Bestelling object to each Bestellingsregel object in the list. Bestellingsregel is owning side, so you have to set reference directly before save.
2. Make your relationship unidirectional: remove Bestelling reference from Bestellingsregel and redefine our `@OneToMany` relationship

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, , orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "bestelling_id")
   private List<Bestellingsregel> bestellingsregels = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made the relation unidirectional and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Bestelling b = new Bestelling();
    Bestellingsregel br = new Bestellingsregel();
    br.setBestelling(b);
    List<Bestellingsregel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(br);
    b.setBestellingsregels(list);
    repo.save(b);
```

This worked for me. I guess you are not setting the Bestelling object in the Bestellingsregel object.

Comment: Shouldn't Hibernate do this?